# android - unload ImageView image from memeory when it goes off screen inside ScrollView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I have multiple imageView added in a scrollview. and if the images are a lot then I am getting OutOfMemeory error. so my question is how can I unload an ImageView image from memory when it goes off screen..

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to just have the bitmaps themselves load and unload on demand.  I say "easier" because Android has built-in support for this.

```
Resources r = getResources();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.image1, options);
imageView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.image2, options);
```

The magic here is in the `inPurgeable` and `inInputShareable` options.  When these options are used, Android allocates the bitmap on a special heap where it can be quickly discarded under memory pressure, and Android will automatically re-decode a purged bitmap when it needs to be displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can have a try with volley library introduced at google i/o 2013.