# running of out of memory android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I made custom gallery app with gallery view and image view.its working nice in 4.2 devices,but its getting force closes in 2.3.3

```
    myHorizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // if (lastview != null)
            // lastview.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            // lastview = arg1;
            // arg1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            p=position;

            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemsArray[position]);}}
```

i think this code caused running out of memory,because every time i am setting new picture under old picture

```
                 imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemsArray[position])
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: one another Reason is that you use large size image,reduce that maybe work fine

Comment: Out of memory because the high resolution of images,.... So you need to reduce the resolution of image and also create a new resize bitmap object of that image..

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan ya i have reduced Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload ur image in imageview in smaller size

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Clear itemsArray after use (may be at finally) and also try to reduce the image size!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you purge your images and make their memory sharable ([android - unload ImageView image from memeory when it goes off screen inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801589/android-unload-imageview-image-from-memeory-when-it-goes-off-screen-inside-scr)). This (kinda, Google it for a deeper explanation) happens automatically on ICS+.